# Доступ в функциях js

Tags: функции, javascript

Добрый день!

Есть код:

```
OBJ = function(arr){
    ON=true;

    function test(){
    console.log(ON);
    }

}

OBJ.prototype = {
start: function(){
    ON = true;
    OBJ.test;//Доступ к функции test внутри OBJ!!!!
},
stop: function(){
    ON = false;
}
}
```

Не работает эта часть `OBJ.test;`.
Должно запускать функцию `test` из `OBJ`, но не работает. По крайней мере я так думаю, что должно.

Что неверно?

**Обновление**

Функция, которая будет работать с картинкой и создавать анимацию, а точнее переходить по пикселях через определенный интервал. Функция `test` отвечает за переход на другие пиксели (внутри нее есть определенный интервал, через который будет делать переход, она рекурсивная). Функции `start` и `stop` обеспечивают запуск и остановку таких переходов. `Start` изменяет параметр `On` на `true` и вызывает функцию `test`, которая продолжит или начнет перемещение по картинке, по пикселям. `Stop` изменит параметр `ON` на `false`, что остановит роботу рекурсивной функции `test` благадоря `if(ON){test();}`, что и остановит анимацию.

Answer (score 1):

Изучайте области видимости, чтобы понять ошибку.

1. Переменные внутри функции, которые создаются без ключевого слова var, проваливаются в глобальную область видимости и доступны из любого участка кода.
2. Переменные, которые созданы во внутренней области видимости функции, не доступны извне.

Ваша работа с переменной ON возможна только потому, что она провалилась в глобальную область и доступна отовсюду. А вот функции не проваливаются, и, соответственно, к ней доступа вообще нет извне.

Если ваша цель создать из функции объект, то надо бы оставлять привязку к объекту через this. Хотя, возможно, я неправильно понял Ваши цели.

```
OBJ = function(arr){
    this.ON = true;
    this.test = function (){
        console.log(this.ON);
    }
}

OBJ.prototype = {
    start: function(){
        this.ON = true;
        this.test();
    },
    stop: function(){
        this.ON = false;
    }
}

o = new OBJ();
o.stop();
o.start();
```

Comment: Вроде все так, только пишет

>this.test is not a function

Если я пишу `this.test();`, если я пишу `this.test;`, то просто не работает.

Comment: this.ON почему то undefined

Comment: Вы лучше расскажите, что Вы вообще хотите сделать и какое поведение ожидаете. А то просто простыня кода с пометкой "не работает" это очень мало, для понимания поставленной задачи в данном случае.

Comment: Функция которая будет работать с картинкой и создавать анимацию, а точнее переходить по пикселях через определенный интервал. Функция test отвечает за переход на другие пиксели(внутри нее есть определенный интервал через который будет делать переход, она рекурсивная). Функции start и stop обеспечивают запуск и остановку таких переходов. Start изменяет параметр On на true и вызывает функцию test которая продолжит или начнет перемещение по картинке, по пикселям. Stop изменит параметр ON на false что остановит роботу рекурсивной функции test благадоря if(ON){test();} что и остановит анимацию.

Comment: @M11, на самом деле, я не совсем понимаю, зачем Вам нужно использовать прототип и такие странные области видимости, если вы пишите функцию. У меня просто складывается ощущение, что вы пытаетесь использовать возможности языка, которые Вы не совсем понимаете и тут совершенно не нужны. Поэтому мне сложно посоветовать что-то конкретное.